# Mined Bitcoin withdrawn but not deposited into wallet yet

Tags: wallet

I mine bitcoin with effort and yesterday I withdrew a third of bitcoin, but it has not been deposited into my wallet yet. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Sounds like you are being scammed. This is not how bitcoin or mining works.

Answer (score 2):

A common scam is to offer X much for remote mining or mining on your computer, but it doesn't mine anything. In fact, unless you bought one of the *most recent bitcoin miners*, there's no profit. But if you did so, it'd be near impossible for you to mine third of bitcoin, $5k! Whoever offered you this, if they ask you for more money so that you can withdraw, this is the continuation of the scam. Don't pay them anything and don't expect from them anything. I'm sorry for your loss.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it took almost 4 years to mine a third of Bitcoin, and she didn't ask me for money

Comment: In the installed program, check confirmation

Comment: @ابراهیمجمالی What's the program called? You cannot mine a third of Bitcoin in the last four years even if you had bought a specifically designed ASIC computers.

Comment: Send me a message to my email so I can send a photo of the program
ebi657113@gmail.com

Comment: Please edit your question post to add the picture there, if it provides context to your question.

Comment: @ابراهیمجمالی Tell us its name, that should be enough

Comment: https://btcfree.win/?r=818921

Comment: Log in through Google and enter the email, thank you for the answer, thank you

Answer (score 2):

When Bitcoin was invented, if you mined bitcoin, the mining rewards were paid directly into your wallet. There was no need for any separate withdrawal or deposit process.

Nowadays, mining is almost always done using mining pools. I believe mining pools pay pool members directly into their wallets. If not, the payment arrangements would be a private matter between you and whoever runs the mining pool you use.

The Bitcoin network itself does not have any process for withdrawal or deposit.

If someone claims to have paid you but you don't see the payment in your wallet, one of the following is probably the cause:

- your wallet isn't synchronised with the network yet.
- you gave the other party the wrong address.
- the other party used the wrong address.
- the other party is cheating you.